# Change Global Timeout duration in Cloudbees

Tags: linux, jenkins, jmeter, cloudbees

i am using jenkins in cloudbees to establish the connecction between my linux machine and execute my tets scripts but connection timeouts in 480mins so the test which are configured for 14hrs are failing due to this,is there any chance to change the connection time out settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This global timeout is set to prevent hung builds to burn all your cloudbees credit. If you have such a long build to run we can change this value. Please open a support ticket on support.cloudbees.com with the max value you'd like to set for a build

Answer (score 0):

This configuration is available under:

```
Manage Jenkins > Configure System > Global build timeout in minutes
```